# Query for which vehicle is available on for a booking

Tags: php, sql

I have a database for a car rental and I am trying to run a query that returns which vehicle is available between two dates. i.e. start and finish date. I only want to see what vehicles are available from a certain date that I enter.

I am having trouble getting this to run. It is currently just returning all the vehicles and not between the dates. The vehicles rented table shouldn't affect the query but it is in the middle.

I will post the design:

[image]

Sample:

[image: Booking]
Sample:

[image: Answer]

```
SELECT v.*
FROM vehicles AS v 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.* 
           FROM booking AS b 
           WHERE b.end_rent_date >= 2016-12-09 and b.start_rent_date <= 2016-12-18
          )  AS b ON v.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
WHERE b.vehicle_id is null
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: What are the results of the query in your question?

Comment: I am currently getting all the vehicles back when running the query but i should only get the vehicles which are not being rented between 09 and 18 of december

Comment: put some sample data and expected outcome in your question please

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` will provide direct responce to the question

Comment: cars that are available in the period you want, will they be in the booking table ? If not than you need a NOT EXISTS

Comment: Not related to your question, but all you need in the select clause of your subquery is vehicle_id.  To troubleshoot, run the subquery by itself and see what it returns.  I don't think you need a not exists.

Comment: how does the not exist function work i am not familiar with it. I have posted what the booking table and vehicle table looks like if that provides further clarification

Comment: @leonHill What RDBMS you're using? Try putting dates in your inner query in quotes, i.e. b.end_rent_date >= '2016-12-09' and b.start_rent_date <= '2016-12-18'.

Comment: Please do not overwrite a question with its answer, otherwise new readers will obviously be confused when you present a working query as exhibiting an error.

Comment: I've downvoted, and will happily undownvote when this question is tagged with the appropriate RDBMS - MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? etc. This has been asked three times now.

Comment: Voting to close (see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with dates in your inner query. I haven't got an error on such condition at MS SQL, so may be you are using this RDBMS. Simply, put the dates in quotes in order to date convertion work right.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM vehicles AS v 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.* 
           FROM booking AS b 
           WHERE b.end_rent_date >= '2016-12-09' and b.start_rent_date <= '2016-12-18'
          )  AS b ON v.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
WHERE b.vehicle_id is null
```